# Use Elasticsearch percolate with specific type of field name

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm making a subscription system for notifications using the percolate type of property of Elasticsearch 7.x. The problem is that I can't make a percolate query with certain types of fields.

This is an example of the indexed data. As you can see, I have a query indexed to be able to perform a percolate query. The difference I would like to mention is the name of the field in the query which can be `state` or `created_by.full_name.raw`

```
{
    "_index": "widgets_2020",
    "_type": "widget",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "created_at": "2020-01-09T21:58:14.123Z",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [],
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "terms": {
                            "created_by.full_name.raw": [
                                "Ivan Ledner"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "_index": "widgets_2020",
    "_type": "widget",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "created_at": "2020-01-09T22:02:24.133Z",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [],
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "terms": {
                            "state": [
                                "done"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I do something like this, Elasticsearch returns the documents I expect.

```
widgets_2020/_search

{
    "query" : {
        "percolate" : {
            "field" : "query",
            "document" : {
                "state": ["created"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I search this, It returns nothing.

```
widgets_2020/_search

{
    "query" : {
        "percolate" : {
            "field" : "query",
            "document" : {
                "created_by.full_name.raw": ["Ivan Ledner"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a different way of dealing with these types of names? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I enabled the option map_unmapped_fields_as_text and this mapped all my fields as text as the options say. The way I solved this is mapping all the attributes manually and the percolator started to work as expected.